# c++ dynamic libarary fundamentals

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, g++, mingw

`Using GCC 4.6.2 [MinGW]`

I am a bit confused about dynamic libraries, I know they have been discussed a lot on SO but none of the previous posts answer my question.

Lets take a simple example:

File 1: `main.cpp`

```
#include "function.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

File 2: `function.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void display()  
{
    cout << "testing..." << endl;
}
```

And then I do the following:

`g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o`

`g++ -c function.cpp -o function.o`

`g++ -shared function.o -o libfunction.dll`

`g++ main.o -Lfunction.dll -o result.exe`

On doing this the program works.

So in the directory we have files: `main.cpp, function.cpp, main.o, function.o, libfunction.dll` and `result.exe`

But then if I were to delete the SHARED LIBRARY `libfunction.dll` the program still works. How is that possible? I thought the whole idea of shared library
is that the required code to RUN is borrowed during RUN TIME and the absence of `libfunction.dll` should surely give me an error of the missing library.

For this I have looked into the compiler documentation but did not help

Comment: Remove `include<iostream>` from "function.cpp" and do `gcc -E main.cpp`. You'll know what `#include "function.cpp"`does !

Comment: Because of the "#include "function.cpp", you're not even using shared libraries.  Use #include with header files, and use header files to define the interface, not the implementation.   ALSO: "-L" is incorrect - you want "-l" instead.

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes did try as you suggested i.e. to declare the function.cpp in a separate header file and just include the header file in main.cpp but that did not make any difference. Moreover the -L works as it is in the same directory

Comment: @mrdigital do you know what `#include` does ? Learn how to use `dllexport` and `dllimport`, simply saying does work won't help. Also for you just need to declare the `display` not to define it in `main.cpp`

Comment: @P0W I guess you are right. I will try to learn `dllexport` and `dllimport` and use a `import library` maybe that will make sense.

Comment: @mrdigital you don't have to use import library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including `function.cpp` into the `main.cpp` file. The definition (body) of the `display()` function will be compiled and linked along with it.

To experience the expected behavior (and to write **sane** code), don't `#include` implementation files. Pull out the declarations into a separate header file, and only include that header file.

Comment: Yes I did that as well but it did not make any difference; included a header file and then declared the function.cpp in it

Comment: @mrdigital Now that doesn't make any sense. What is meant by "declared function.cpp in it"?

Comment: @H2CO3 I think OP just created a new file "function.h" defined `display` in that and included it in "main.cpp", resulting in same thing

Comment: @H2CO3 @POW Actually NO that is not what i meant. I created a `head.h` and then put in it `#include "function.cpp"`

Comment: @mrdigital That is equally wrong, it results in **exactly** the same behavior that P0W pointed out. And it is **not** what I described in my answer. Read about the preprocessor, you are very confused and you don't accept good advice.

Comment: Yes i do agree it is the same thing. Also I think I will go back to your first answer and implement the whole thing in a header file and convert that into a shared library.

Comment: @ H2CO3 @P0W Thanks that works now; I was failing to understand that on my every approach I was linking it in one way or the other; Thanks again for bearing with me

Answer (score 3):

`#include "function.cpp"` makes all definitions from *function.cpp* available in *main.cpp*.

To prevent that, write a header that *declares* the funcions from *function.cpp* and include that header in *main.cpp*. Then compile *main.cpp* and link against the DLL. See [HOWTO Create and Deploy a Sample DLL using MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL) on the MinGW website for details.

Comment: but how would I do it otherwise? any examples of direct linking? which does not include - import libraries using (dllexport)

Comment: @Oswald yes I did visit the page before posting on here; I did not want to use the IMPORT LIBRARY (dllexport) method and wanted to use direct linking with all symbols exported by default